# How to set padding on map view (Mapbox-ios-sdk)

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapbox

Does anybody knows how to set the padding on a MapBox mapView as Google Maps iOS SDK does?.

This example belongs to google maps iOS sdk 1.7.2 (VisibleRegionViewController).

[image]

What I want to do is to replicate the overlay view on MapBox SDK for iOS so I can keep the MapBox watermark logo visible when an overlay view is over the mapView.

Comment: Could you provide a clarifying example for Google? Are you trying to set a map region with a boundary padding?

Comment: Hi @incanus, you can see an example on the image above. Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Do you mean some sort of padding, or just changing the frame of the map view? I don't understand "overlay" in the context that you are using it. It just looks like a basemap without any overlays.

Comment: I believe he's talking about a MapBox iOS SDK equivalent to [Google MapView's "padding" property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view#a66668a48bbc864faee1e8ba71e4c9bec).

Answer (score 0):

I contacted MapBox support with the same question in 07/2014 and this was the response:

"Hi, No, there is no documentation for either of these use cases as they are somewhat custom.

We might add this sort of functionality in the future, but it's not there right now."

It looks like they don't provide a Google Maps equivalent of "padding".